# Idiomas se confundem entre as versões das comunidades SO

Tags: bug, status-aceito

Fiz inscrição do [SO-JA](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) e percebi uma confusão nos labels do site

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que isso deveria ser reportado no StackExchange, mas achei mais conveniente postar aqui mesmo pois não costumo usar tanto os sites da rede e não disponho de tempo para procurar onde e como reportar. Talvez alguém aqui saiba como proceder.

Essa notificação com idioma misturado acontece quando navega em sites da rede em idiomas diferentes um do outro.

Originalmente, navegando pelo SO-PT, é assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu recebi o badge e os pontos no SO-pt, ambos ficam com descrição em português mesmo navegando em sites com outros idiomas.

Testando em outros sites em inglês podemos ver a mistura também:

https://serverfault.com/

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Presumo que o problema seja oriundo do provedor dos labels em questão. Parece que uma parte é oriundo do site original e outros são do site onde navega.

Também não acho que seja bug mas não tem outra tag melhor e é obrigado a adicionar uma tag. Apesar de não ser bug é uma "falha de design" ou intencional. Mesmo que seja intencional é uma falha de design. Não me refiro ao título original da pergunta ser traduzido mas me refiro aos labels, por exemplo “necromante” e o trecho entre parênteses que resume o que é o badge recebido e a quantidade de pontos recebidos. Esses poderiam estar com tradução de acordo com o ambiente onde navega pois são labels fixos.

Uma hipótese que imagino é que os badges e suas respectivas traduções são independentes para cada site e ficam sem tradução para outros idiomas.

Esse é o ponto falho no design, independente de ser intencional ou não.

Comment: Como eu disse, necromance não é label, é medalha, e todas medalhas tem seus titulos e descrições adaptados para cada comunidade, por exemplo no SOen temos a medalha `mortarboard` aqui a equivalente se chama `capelo`, note que elas são equivalentes e não a mesma, eles podem ter requisitos iguais, mas o tanto de pontos ou atividades podem variar de comunidade para comunidade. Elas são traduzidas pois apesar de equivalentes elas só valem para aquela comunidade especifica, como eu citei na resposta: *"não tem relação com as medalhas de outras comunidades."*

Comment: @Gabe não sei, se aceito ok, mas veja esse meu ultimo comentário.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento [tag:status-aceito] não significa que é um bug confirmado, significa só que vai ser dada uma olhada e ver o que dá pra fazer. Pode ser que fique assim, pode ser que mude.

Comment: @Gabe ;) justo!

Comment: O termo "label" a que me refiro é o texto que traduz o objeto, @GuilhermeNascimento. Estou num tablet. É meio complicado postar algo mais detalhado. Mais tarde farei uma ilustração. Mas é isso mesmo que estou entendendo. Conforme descrevi, parece que são textos sem tradução pois são independentes para cada site.  Acho que poderia resolver abrindo um recurso para a comunidade traduzir ou sugerir traduções para esses "labels/textos". Mas aí depedende de como está a estrutura do sistema.

Comment: O Label ao qual se refere é o que eu citei como "Descrição" na resposta, é como eu disse cada site tem seu próprio texto, adaptado para necessidade daquela comunidade, ou seja não é uma tradução automatica assim como os demais itens do [Stack Exchange Button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button), todavia aguardemos o retorno do @Gabe e/ou staff ;)

Comment: rsrs  mas é o mesmo que eu coloquei na pergunta. No penultimo paragrafo deixei mais claro... rsrs

Comment: Editei a resposta, na parte **Resumindo**: *Isso ocorre porque as medalhas tem seus títulos e descrição/labels traduzidos "manualmente" dentro do site de origem e não tem relação com as medalhas de outras comunidades, pois os textos podem ser adaptados a cada condição necessária para aquela comunidade (um critério/requisito de uma medalha pode ser diferente da medalha equivalente outra comunidade).*. De qualquer forma aguardemos um retorno da staff ;)

Answer (score 4):

Não creio que seja um bug, me parece [status-intencional](/questions/tagged/status-intencional) (by design), ali está avisando que ganhou a medalha conforme o idioma do site, todavia a pergunta tem o titulo em portugues, então tem que manter o título tal como é o original.

Tanto que se abrir o ["Stack Exchange Button"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) no pt.stackoverflow.com e tiver recebido uma medalha por algo feito em uma comunidade em inglês, vai notar que a descrição é em português, mas o título em inglês, o que me parece correto, já que a pergunta foi feito em outra comunidade, mas a ferramenta está sendo chamada em uma comunidade de diferente idioma, veja o exemplo a seguir:

[image: medalha do meta.stackexchange no achivements no pt.stackoverflow]

Essa medalha eu ganhei no http://meta.stackexchange.com, mas abri o menu Achivements (Realizações) no pt.stackoverflow.com, a descrição mostra `Você ganhou a medalha ...`, o resto é texto do site.

Agora posso presumir que você esteja se referindo ao título estar no meio do texto em japonês, no caso os sinais `「...」`, assim:

> 「foo bar baz, etc, etc, etc 」

Na verdade eles são como aspas, eu não entendo do idioma, mas é o que posso presumir, então me parece correto colocar os títulos entre elas, já que se abrir o ["Stack Exchange Button"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) dentro de um site de idioma diferente ele deve ajudar pessoas daquele idioma.

### Resumindo

Então na sua postagem a mensagem *"Qual é a utilidade de declarar variáveis através de chavetas?"* é o título e tem que se manter no idioma escrito e a medalha *"necromante"* e a *descrição/label* *"Respondeu uma pergunta com mais de 60 dias e 5 ou mais pontos"* também tem que se manter em português.

Isso ocorre porque as medalhas tem seus títulos e descrição/labels traduzidos **"manualmente"** dentro do site de origem e não tem relação com as medalhas de outras comunidades, pois os textos podem ser adaptados a cada condição necessária para aquela comunidade (um *critério/requisito* de uma medalha pode ser diferente da medalha equivalente outra comunidade).